# Git permission denied inside Docker container

Tags: git, shell, docker, jenkins, ssh

I am using a shell script as the part of Jenkinsfile to run database migration. The shell script attempts to clone a repository after setting an entry in `known_hosts` file. I am doing the following :

```
    #!/bin/bash

    set -e

    # Workaround old docker images with incorrect $HOME
    # check https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2968 for details
    if [ "${HOME}" = "/" ]
    then
      export HOME=$(getent passwd $(id -un) | cut -d: -f6)
    fi

    mkdir -p ~/.ssh

    echo '
    github.com ssh-rsa KEY
  ' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

    git clone git@github.com:Organization/migrations.git /tmp/database-migrations

   Execute Migration
```

This gives me an error which is

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

How can solve this ?

BTW when I check the known hosts file, I am seeing an entry has been added to the file with an IP which is `192` range (local IP). Is this creating the problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not because the known_hosts file. As it said, I think it's your private key.

Have you copy the right private key into your container?  'cause I didn't see it in your script.

You can test your key by typing:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I beleive you'll see the same result.

And you can check this link [Error: Permission denied (publickey)](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/) on github.

Comment: Then, how to solve it for container?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to use SSH for just cloning right? Why not use https URL to clone the repository, that worked for me. I think when just cloning a repo https with an access token is much simpler and as secure. Adding SSH can make your container bigger and potentially slower [check this issue](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/255).

You can use this instead:

```
git clone https://{{YOUR_USER_NAME}}:{{YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}}@gitlab.com/{{REPO_URL}}.git
```

There is also debate on whether using SSH in containers is good practice altogether.
[Hacker News: Docker Container Shouldn't Run SSH Server](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7950326)